# twitter bootstrap tab set input focus when tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs to create tabs in my forms. 
What i need is to set focus on first `input="text"` that is displayed. 
 
I was unable to find it in documentation or elsewhere.

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#login1">
      <span class="icon-key"></span>Login</a>
   </li>
   <li class="">
      <a data-toggle="tab" href="#register1"><span class="icon-user"></span>Register
      </a>   
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div id="login1" class="tab-pane active">
      <input type="text"> <!-- focus when tab clicked -->
   </div>
   <div id="register1" class="tab-pane">
      <input type="text"> <!-- focus when tab clicked -->
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first input field will not be automatically focused you can do the following:

```
$('input').first().focus();
```

This will focus the input field.
You might even want to do it on document ready as an initiation script, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').first().focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it manually if you want..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tab-pane").on('click', function(){
        $(this).find("input[type=text]").filter(':visible:first').focus();
    });
});
```

Hoe that helps..